# Failing in XSL Transformation because of Namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Below is a response XML I get from a service I created-

```
  <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
       <env:Header>
          <wsa:MessageID>urn:3474700f-5fc9-11e6-ba99-00144ff9e607</wsa:MessageID>
          <wsa:ReplyTo>
             <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
             <wsa:ReferenceParameters>
                <instra:tracking.ecid xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">fc5bd4a9-5dea-4f03-bef5-b62057ff17d5-00055065</instra:tracking.ecid>
                <instra:tracking.FlowEventId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">280018</instra:tracking.FlowEventId>
                <instra:tracking.FlowId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">140005</instra:tracking.FlowId>
                <instra:tracking.CorrelationFlowId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">0000LPtpMnV4Muk_Ox5Eid1Ncr^i000006</instra:tracking.CorrelationFlowId>
             </wsa:ReferenceParameters>
          </wsa:ReplyTo>
          <wsa:FaultTo>
             <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
          </wsa:FaultTo>
       </env:Header>
       <env:Body>
          <SCOR_SCORING_RES>
             <TABLE>
                <RESULT>
                   <CALC_MAX_REPAYMENT_CLIENT>100000</CALC_MAX_REPAYMENT_CLIENT>
                   <INTERNAL_CREDIT_RATING_CD>3</INTERNAL_CREDIT_RATING_CD>
                   <OUTCOME_CD>Good</OUTCOME_CD>
                   <CALC_MAX_LIMIT_ALTERN>50000</CALC_MAX_LIMIT_ALTERN>
                </RESULT>
             </TABLE>
          </SCOR_SCORING_RES>
       </env:Body>
    </env:Envelope>
```

I want to apply XSLT on this XML and get data. 
I have written a small XSLT code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="Envelope">
          <xsl:value-of select="Body/SCOR_SCORING_RES/TABLE/RESULT/CALC_MAX_REPAYMENT_CLIENT"/>~
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the result XML doesn't give me the value of tag CALC_MAX_REPAYMENT_CLIENT but the below result which is value of all the tags in response XML-

```
urn:3474700f-5fc9-11e6-ba99-00144ff9e607http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymousfc5bd4a9-5dea-4f03-bef5-b62057ff17d5-000550652800181400050000LPtpMnV4Muk_Ox5Eid1Ncr^i000006http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous1000003Good50000
```

From my very little knowledge of XSLT and XPATH, Body/SCOR_SCORING_RES/TABLE/RESULT/CALC_MAX_REPAYMENT_CLIENT should return only one value. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with namespaces. The `Envelope` and `Body` elements are in a namespace in your input XML, but you have not accounted for that in your XSLT. In your XSLT, you are trying to match an `Envelope` with no space, which is not the same thing.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

  <xsl:template match="env:Envelope">
    <xsl:value-of select="env:Body/SCOR_SCORING_RES/TABLE/RESULT/CALC_MAX_REPAYMENT_CLIENT"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The reason the original code was returning all of the data is that it hadn't overridden the default XSLT processing rules. Adding an `<xsl:template match=/"><xsl:apply-templates select="env:Envelope"/></xsl:template>` would prevent other data from passing through.